# Next.js rewrites work, but Javascript and CSS is 404

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to run multiple Vercel/Next.js projects under the same domain as [suggested on this guide](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-serve-multiple-projects-under-a-single-domain).

All of my different apps have very different requirements so, it makes sense for me to separate them into their own projects.

I have a main Next.js project which will run at `mysite.com`. This project contains rewrites to the other projects:

```
const rewrites = async () => [
  {
    source: "/topic/",
    destination: "https://forums.mysite.com/topic/",
  },
  {
    source: "/topic/:match*",
    destination: "https://forums.mysite.com/topic/:match*",
  },
];

/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  rewrites,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

These rewrites are working, kind of. If I visit `mysite.com/topic/` Next.js attempt to load the site at `forums.mysite.com`, however it never displays because all Javascript scripts go to 404.

It's essentially attempting to load `forums.mysite.com`'s scripts on `mysite.com`'s domain, where they obviously don't exist.

Is there any way around this? Seems like a pretty big oversight but this is definitely [the way that Next.js suggests this is done](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites#incremental-adoption-of-nextjs).

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is actually caused by the way Next.js loads its scripts. They're all absolute to the root (`/_next/script` instead of (`https://example.com/_next/script`).

So the solution is to use the `assetPrefix` config:

```
const nextConfig = {
  rewrites,
  assetPrefix: 'https://example.com',
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```